# how to use python varname to get var names inside loops

Tags: python

I'm using the fantastic `varname` python package https://pypi.org/project/varname/ to print python var names from inside the code:

```py
    >>> from varname import nameof
    >>> myvar = 42
    >>> print(f'{nameof(myvar)} + 8: {myvar + 8}')
    myvar + 8: 50
    >>>
```

but when I try to use it in a loop:

```py
    >>> a, b, c, d = '', '', '', ''
    >>> for i in (a, b, c, d):
        print(f'{nameof(i)}') 
    i
    i
    i
    i
    >>>
```

I do not get to print a, b, c, ...

How could I get something like this ?:

```
a 
b
c
d
```

Comment: There is exactly one empty string object in your script, with five names referring to it.  Any one of those names has exactly equal claim to being *the* name of the empty string;  it's pure coincidence that `i` happened to be the name that was shown.  The whole concept of `nameof()` is flawed; it simply does not reflect how Python actually works.

Comment: @jasonharper it frightens me that anyone even attempted to create a library such as the one being asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `for` loop into a function, and then use `argname`:

```
from varname import argname
a, b, c, d = '1', '2', '3', '4'
def fun(*args):
    names = argname('args')
    for i, name_of_i in zip(args, names):
        print(f'Variable name: {name_of_i}  Value: {i}')
```

Output of `fun(a,b,c,d)`:

```
Variable name: a  Value: 1
Variable name: b  Value: 2
Variable name: c  Value: 3
Variable name: d  Value: 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Wrapper](https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname#value-wrapper), to see *varname* in a loop then.

```
from varname.helpers import Wrapper

a = Wrapper('')
b = Wrapper('')
c = Wrapper('')
d = Wrapper('')


def values_to_dict(*args):
    return {val.name: val.value for val in args}


mydict = values_to_dict(a, b, c, d)
print(mydict)
# {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': '', 'd': ''}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've never used `nameof()`, but in your loop, it's always going to return `i`, because that's what you've asked for with `for i in (a,b,c,d):` All that is doing, is to iterate over the tuple, assigning each element of the tuple to `i`, then printing the 'name', which is, logically, always going to be `i`.

Comment: is this an answer?